# How to set a Seaborn scatterplot hue equal to features and not the values of a single feature?

Tags: python, seaborn, data-science, data-visualization

I would like to create a scatterplot in Seaborn that sets the hue parameter so that values are coloured based on what feature they are from. (All features have values 0 to 100)

For example, supposing I have the following dataframe:

```
      Happiness      Kindness     Sadness
1        100           70            0
2        60            50            1
3        34            32            10
4        23            65            54
5        43            54            87
```

When plotting the values, I would like to set all the values under happiness to red, kindness to blue, sadness to green. However, with Seaborn's scatterplot, the hue parameter only accepts one variable under the dataframe. Documentation here: http://man.hubwiz.com/docset/Seaborn.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html

I want to know if there are any workarounds to the only one variable being accepted feature so I can use the hue parameter to distinguish between the different variables.

Comment: Is this your intended outcome? `df = df.unstack().to_frame(name='value');sns.scatterplot(data=df, x=df.index.get_level_values(0), y='value', hue=df.index.get_level_values(0))`

Comment: Hey there, thanks for responding to my question. 

I tried it out however I'm now receiving this error: ValueError: Could not interpret value `value` for parameter `y`

Comment: Your data is in horizontal format, so you are converting it to vertical format. The column name of the value is set to 'value' at that time. Did you execute both lines?

Comment: My mistake, I didn't separate the two lines. Yes! It did work, thank you so much for your help!